# What is the solution for the wait?

Tags: java

I have this code and I want to put a waiting..i tried thread.sleep() but it isn't good because it holds the button for 1 second..i think i need here a wait() but i don't know..please help me, thank you
So my question is that how to wait in actionlistener?

```
  button[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
    button[1].setIcon(elemek[1]);
    p+=1;
    g[0]=t[1];
    //here i want to wait 1 second
  dosomething
    }});
```

thoughts?

Comment: Put the wait and `dosomething` into a background task: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need wait in some code but not block the UI you have to run this code in separate thread and wait in this thread with  `thread.sleep()`

Something like this

```
button[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
       Thread worker = new Thread(new Runable(){
           public void run(){
              button[1].setIcon(elemek[1]);
              p+=1;
              g[0]=t[1];
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              //dosomething
           }});
        worker.start();

    }});
```